# Blazor WASM is it possible to have multiple server projects

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

When creating a new WASM ASP.NET Core Hosted Blazor app, three projects are created by default:

- Project.Client
- Project.Server
- Project.Shared

Is it possible to Add multiple Server projects to a solution and be able to call the controllers in them?  Eg:

- Project.Client
- Project.Server.Users
- Project.Server.Orders
- Project.Server.Customers
- Project.Server.Shared

The reason behind this is because our team wants to encapsulate functional areas into their own projects, similar to vertical slice architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can even call servers outside this Solution and from other companies written in other languages.

But with multiple servers you will have to configure CORS on all (but one) of them.

> because our team wants to encapsulate functional areas into their own projects

This is also very much possible with 1 Server. Split the areas into Class libraries and use the main Server project to host them collectively.
This would be my preference.